# Multithreaded Pipeline for Java(7)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, pipeline

I'm building a summarizer and I need a pipeline implementation.
I've used my own implementation, but as the work grows I see that it just won't cut.

Is there a mature framework in java that provides me with the foundation (basically the synchronization logic)?

I need to declare a stage, and each stage has workers, the workers process items and return results to the stage, which sends it to next stages (might fan out).

The whole point of my implementation was to give me this foundation however it doesn't work properly (race condition which brings to a deadlock)

I've tried getting the apache library (which is dead basically) but it doesn't have the feature to create stage workers.

Comment: Why don't you just call each of the workers in order?  Do you know that using multiple threads is faster than using just one thread?

Comment: I have n stages, each stage has m_n workers, each worker runs on a separate thread to maximize efficiency. some stages fan out (output to more than 1 stage). My implementation worked until yesterday, however, is stopped working and I can't seem to find the bug. I've gone frustrated with it (it has way too much bugs and is not a direct part of my project) and hope to find in stock overflow someone with an advice. [link](http://bitbucket.org/nocgod/parallel-pipeline-processing-library) This is my library, lacks generics and is not relieable.

Comment: This is my point, have you measured that it maximise efficiency or that it maximises overhead? You can add far more overhead than you gain by multiple threads if you haven't done this research and you end up with code which is much more complicated and unreliable.

Comment: I've tested and found the right balance of threads that works great. The runtimes are cut in half when I used the multithreaded pipeline, however my implementation is not reliable and I can't waste time meddling with it while I have a summarizer and a GA to implement. That's why I hopped someone on stack overflow could throw me a bone with a mature framework he/she used.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect all your stages with blocking queues, and everything would work reliably. Use bounded [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) to avoid saturation of queues if producers work faster than consumers.

Most pipeline/dataflow/actor frameworks deal with tasks so small that assigning even single thread to a stage would be an overhead so stages share a thread pool, and so have limited number of working threads. The only framework which (probably) exploits several threads per stage is [FBP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flow-based-pgmg/), but I am not sure.

Comment: If you peek at my library, you'll see that's what I've done. Each stage is coupled with the next stages, data flows through Observer pattern (maybe I should just pass the blocking queue of the next stage?) and I use a single thread pool of 8 threads for my whole program, I do not waste time on creating/destroying threads.

Comment: I've downloaded your library but found no tests or examples, so it's hard to restore how it is supposed to be used and so whether the implementation correctly follows the idea.

Comment: Yeah I didn't create any examples since I'm the sole user or this library... Sorry about that...

Comment: Queus are more natural and reliable approach than observer/observable pattern. But using queues directly in tasks running on a thread pool is problematic as blocking `take` operation blocks underlying thread and this may cause thread starvation (a kind of deadlock). The solution is to exit from `Runnable.run()` when there is no data, and resubmit the task when the data appear. Evaluate my library https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core/README.md which implements this solution.

Comment: I definitely will take a look at your library. Please do take a look at mine again, I've added 2 examples (1 staged and 2 staged) they are very simplistic and don't really represent what I've envisioned but they do pass the general idea.

Comment: I looked at your library and found that `oneStagePrimeExample` does not find any prime number and `twoStagePrimeExample` just hangs. I do not want to debug it as it looks too complicated. Look also at https://github.com/rfqu/pipeline which looks pretty close to what you want. It has no embedded capability to parallelize one stage in several workers, however, it can be achieved using https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core/src/com/github/rfqu/df4j/ext/Dispatcher.java .

Comment: @Alexi Kaigorodov Sorry you are right. I've fixed the examples (the 2 stage example currently gives wrong output due to a race condition in BaseStage update and takeWorkChunk methods). I've went to reserved duty (army) and was not able to update in time.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel: http://camel.apache.org/  does what you describe but might be too intrusive to your existing design.